# copy file from zip and read that file same time

Tags: python, zip

I want to copy a file from Zip file to separate folder and read that file at same time. The file is copied to specific folder if I comment that last two lines.

The code I tried is:

```
import os
import shutil
import zipfile

zip_filepath='/home/sundeep/Desktop/SCHEMA AUTOMATION/SOURCE/DSP8010_2017.1.zip'
target_dir='/home/sundeep/Desktop/SCHEMA AUTOMATION/SCHEMA'


with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filepath) as z:
    with z.open('DSP8010_2017.1/json-schema/AccountService.json') as zf, open(os.path.join(target_dir, os.path.basename('AccountService.json')), 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(zf, f)
        with open('AccountService.json') as json_data:
            j=json.load(json_data)
```

But it gave following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "schema.py", line 21, in <module>
with open('AccountService.json') as json_data:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AccountService.json'
```

My question is it possible to copy that file and read contents of that file same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its not working for you is because the file is not yet closed (written to disk) when you try to read it.

Two ways you can fix this - one is simply by moving the final `with` statement outside of the first `with` statement:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filepath) as z:
    with z.open('DSP8010_2017.1/json-schema/AccountService.json') as zf, open(os.path.join(target_dir, os.path.basename('AccountService.json')), 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(zf, f)
with open('AccountService.json') as json_data:
    j=json.load(json_data)
```

This way, your file *should* be written and available to you.

However, a simpler way is to just read the contents of the zip file, before you copy it:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filepath) as z:
    with z.open('DSP8010_2017.1/json-schema/AccountService.json') as zf, open(os.path.join(target_dir, os.path.basename('AccountService.json')), 'wb') as f:
        j = json.load(zf) # read the contents here.
        shutil.copyfileobj(zf, f) # copy the file

        #with open('AccountService.json') as json_data:
        #    j=json.load(json_data)
```

Now, you don't need to open the other file anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much... Can I edit the contents of that file same time?

Comment: You can do whatever you like to the contents; but then make sure you write your modified contents to the target file, and not just copy it (otherwise, your changes will be overwritten).